# Remove shadow from status bar android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-statusbar

I've used the following in my style to make the status bar transparent:

```
<style name="TransparentStatusBar" parent="ThemeBase">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

But now there's a shadow at the top of the screen where the status bar was:

[image: img]

How can I remove this shadow?

**Edit:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_action_back));
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ToolbarTheme:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeBase">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 10):

Late  to the party!
This black shadow is mainly due to

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

There are two ways you can handle that.

1. You only need to have the same color for status bar as the below view.

   (<sub>This way is if you add a background image you gets caught.Because actually its two views,Status bar and its below View in same color.Yet some people need this!</sub> )

   For this you do not need `android:windowTranslucentStatus`.It will make that black shadow!
   Making `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/asSameColorAsBelowViewColor</item>` you can achieve it.Even this can be applied to OP's question here.But its for colors.Other wise you get trapped.

---

2. You really need to go your view behind `StatusBar`without that black shadow.

   <sub>eg: In a situation that you need to use an image.</sub>

   For this again if you are using `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` you can remove it and add `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>`

   and add  `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);` in your Activity **before** `setContentView()`.